# Delete directories except one sub-directory in Python

Tags: python

I have some directories which I want to delete but one of the directory has a sub-directory that I want to keep.

Example:

> Files
>
> > pictures
> >
> > > cat.png
> > >
> > > icon.png
> >
> > Music
> >
> > > song.mp3
>
> Movies
>
> > First.mp4

I want to delete everything (directories and sub-directories) except the sub-directory pictures for example.

Right now I have this:

```
def Destroy_Path(path):
    shutil.rmtree(path, ignore_errors=True)
```

Comment: Move `pictures` to somewhere else, delete everything, move it back.

Comment: Would you accept any standard *nix tool e.g. `find` based solution?

Comment: @Selcuk Moving, deleting and moving back would not work since intermediate directories would have been deleted in the meantime. One could re-create the required directory structure for each file/folder to be kept, but the meta-data for the intermediate directories (such as permissions and modification dates) would have been lost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. ***UNTESTED!***

Note the use of `os.walk()`'s ability to change `dirnames` in-place to tell it not to recurse into a sub-directory, and the avoidance of using `topdown=False` which would break this feature:

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be
>   used to prune the search, [...]
>   Modifying *dirnames* when *topdown* is `False` has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the directories in *dirnames* are generated before *dirpath* itself is generated.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) for more information.

Also notable is the use of `os.path.samefile()` for path comparisons. This is [available on Windows since version 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile).

*THIS IS UNTESTED!*

**USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!!**

***SERIOUSLY, BE CAREFUL!!!***

```
import os

def gen_dir_paths_except(base_path, exceptions):
    # behave like os.walk(): return nothing if the given path isn't a directory
    if not os.path.isdir(base_path):
        return

    # keep only existing paths in exceptions, so that os.path.samefile() works
    exceptions = list(filter(os.path.exists, exceptions))

    # don't forget the base directory
    if any(os.path.samefile(base_path, x) for x in exceptions):
        return
    yield base_path

    for curr_dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(base_path):    
        # skip directories mentioned in exceptions
        dirnames_to_skip = []
        for dir_name in dirnames:
            dir_path = os.path.join(curr_dirpath, dir_name)
            if any(os.path.samefile(dir_path, x) for x in exceptions):
                dirnames_to_skip.append(dir_name)
            else:
                yield dir_path
        for dir_name in dirnames_to_skip:
            dirnames.remove(dir_name)

def rmtree_except(path, exceptions):
    # Check that the path is actually a directory. This is needed here
    # because os.walk() will silently return nothing for a non-directory.
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            raise OSError("No such directory: " + path)
        else:
            raise OSError("Not a directory: " + path)

    # keep only existing paths in exceptions, so that os.path.samefile() works
    exceptions = list(filter(os.path.exists, exceptions))

    dirs = list(gen_dir_paths_except(path, exceptions))
    # iterate through directories in bottom-up order
    for dir_path in reversed(dirs):
        filenames = [
            x for x in os.listdir(dir_path)
            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_path, x))
        ]
        for file_name in filenames:
            # skip files mentioned in exceptions
            file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
            if not any(os.path.samefile(file_path, x) for x in exceptions):
                os.remove(file_path)

        try:
            os.rmdir(dir_path)
        except OSError: # directory not empty
            pass # just leave the directory
```

Comment: This seems like way overkill. Just define a small function that protects every single folder you're interested in by moving it from the current path to a temp directory, use shutil.rmtree, and then move it back

Or, better yet, open up Nautilus.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Moving, deleting and moving back would not work since intermediate directories would have been deleted in the meantime. One could re-create the required directory structure for each "protected" item, but the meta-data for these directories (such as permissions and modification dates) would have been lost.

Comment: It's a great solution for a complex, comprehensive problem. But unless if it's a highly unusual circumstance (like a remote log, where someone needs write access to a dir but no read access and read access to the parent but no write), simplicity will work just as well in every other case. If they needed to match a given file name, which might be at any level in the directory hierarchy, then a walk approach is great.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh A "simple" solution as you suggest would not actually be significantly simpler: At a minimum, it would have to check if each exception actually exists, move it to a temporary directory, call `rmtree()`, and re-create any intermediate directories *for each protected item* before moving it back.